# ReverseProxy - send some URLs to another server for preprocessing

Tags: apache, apache2, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

There is an existing application hosted on Apache. I want to send some urls(Post Forms) to another server(not apache - just a program) for some preprocessing. This is how this is organized

1) I have added an additional listen port on Apache conf (say 1234)

2)Added a Reverse Proxy on port 80 to send some urls to the 2nd server listening on it's own port

3) Since the actual html is hosted on apache, the 2nd server requests the required page from Apache on port 1234. It then modifies the html(post form) and serves it. It takes the posted data again modifies it & sends it back to apache.

I am able to achieve the above with the following steps
1) In my existing htdocs directory structure - I create 2 new subdirectories called dir1 and dir2

2) All forms which need to be preprocessed, I move to directory dir1. All the scripts which process the post data, I move to dir2. I change other htmls to update the paths.

3) I add the following Proxy confs

`ProxyPass /dir1 http://localhost:1234/dir1`

`ProxyPassReverse /dir1 http://localhost:1234/dir1`

Similiarly for dir2 also.

This is working fine, but I was wondering if these is a better way to do this.
The main improvement I am looking for is to do the reverse proxy configuration in such a way that I do not have disturb the original app hosted in htdocs (by moving stuff to dir1, dir2 - updating references etc). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea behind the setup you describe is somewhat exotic.

I wonder why you cannot simply rewrite the urls of those forms you want to 'intercept' and have request or reply processed by some scripting language like php or whatever. This way you don't need a second server, nothing has to be changed inside the original application layout and you have a full fledged scripting environment right inside apache instead of having to use external programs.

So something like this:

```
get form-1.html 
=> deliver form-1.html 
=> submit form-1.html 
=> process form-1.html

get form-2.html 
!=> rewrite to intercept.php?form=form-2.html
=> intercept form-2.html for preparation
=> deliver intercepted form-2.html
=> submit form-2.html
!=> rewrite to intercept.php?form=form-2.html
=> intercept form-2.html for processing
=> process form-2.html
```

(form-1 is NOT to be intercepted, form-2 IS to be intercepted)

Comment: I already have a second server - to rewrite the whole functionality as a php script is a non-trivial task. My question was how to integrate it with minimum changes to the original setup.

Comment: Ah, ok. Still you could use php as a wrapper and call the "programs" from there to prevent the hassle of using two servers in this rather strange setup. But obviously you are in a better position to judge :-)